# boost::shared_ptr deleter never called iOS simulator

Tags: ios, boost, memory-leaks, ios-simulator

We have one iOS application with 2 project in the one workspace.
And we have got a strange memory leaks: 
if we create boost::shared_ptr with deleter in the second project and start application on simulator - deleter never called.
Same code on the device works correct.
Same code called from main project - works correct on simulator.

Does anyone know how to deal with this problem? I would appreciate any idea.

PS boost version in project v1.55, for boost build use modified version of https://github.com/mgrebenets/boost-xcode5-iosx

PPS If it will explain the situation better: we have checked this situation many times with many codes. Final test was calling   boost::shared_ptr sp( new int[10], []( int *p ) { printf("Deleted\n"); delete[] p; } ); from different parts of projects. The result behavior described in the start of question.

Comment: You don't even show the relevant code. See http://sscce.org

Comment: I don't know what code will relevant here. Test call   boost::shared_ptr<int> sp( new int[10], []( int *p ) { printf("Deleted\n"); delete[] p; } ); work as described in question.

Comment: Your SSCCE. See [Nobody writes testcases anymore](http://kera.name/articles/2013/10/nobody-writes-testcases-any-more/) and [Solve your problem by almost asking a question on StackOverflow](http://blog.jerryorr.com/2014/04/solve-your-problem-by-almost-asking.html). Bottomline: We're not psychic. The only things you list are likely complete [red herrings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_herring).

Comment: I really have no idea why I should post the code in situation when I have different behavior because of the build, but I have updated the question

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question:
I have found next workaround:

1. Move to Xcode 7.0
2. Rebuild boost with "-mios-version-min=7.0" according to http://www.openradar.me/21724015

And memory leaks gone.

Answer (score 0):

The the PPS:

You make it seem like

```
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>

int main()
{
    boost::shared_ptr sp( new int[10], []( int *p ) { printf("Deleted\n"); delete[] p; } );
}
```

would exhibit the problem (have you tried?).

Assuming this is the case, the return question is: *"how do you know it's not being deleted?"*.

In all likelihood, the project is just configured as a non-console type of executable, or some other reason why console output is not showing up.

Comment: From the main project everything works fine: I can see the log output and no memory leaks by Instrument. Form the second project I did not see the log and can see the leaks in this place in the Instruments.

Comment: Maybe you need better language to say what is actually happening. Instead of "the second project" - what kind of a project is that? What property of it makes it not-the-first-project? Why do you have a "second" project? How do you start it? What starts it? IOW: debug your own problem. See the links above.

Comment: My English is not good it is true. And I should improve it. It was not the subject of my question, but thank you for this little help anyway.

Comment: @TinaZh I wasn't talking about your English! I was talking about the _terms_ you use. I explained **exactly** what I mean. For example it's not "the first project", but rather "the project that's first in the list" or "the oldest project" or "the project marked as _startup-project_" or "the project that is started before the other". Then second project is either "a library dependency" or "the client process" or "the unit test container" or "the child project". IOW: you have to be precise. If you /don't know/ the difference between the projects, **find out**. Open the workspace files in a ...

Comment: ... text editor. see what differences exist between the two projects. See also: [Nobody writes testcases anymore](http://kera.name/articles/2013/10/nobody-writes-testcases-any-more/) and [Solve your problem by almost asking a question on StackOverflow](http://blog.jerryorr.com/2014/04/solve-your-problem-by-almost-asking.html).

Answer (score 0):

Yeah you need to build it with the target system min since Xcode 7.

I have a library with this already pre-built here:
https://github.com/danoli3/ofxiOSBoost

- Currently has arm64, armv7, i386, x86_64 Boost 1.59.0 libc++
- Script to build yourself (so if you need libstdc++ quite easy to
  rebuild)

Supports Xcode 7

**ofxiOSBoost**

https://github.com/danoli3/ofxiOSBoost